# O365 Create Events using REST API

Tags: c#, rest, office365

I am trying to call this code

```
 string accessToken = @".."; //valid token with right scopes
 public string EventsUrl = @"https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events";

 // generate body
 var postBody = JsonBody(invite);

 using (var client = new HttpClient())
 {
       using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, EventsUrl))
        {
             request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
             var content = new StringContent(postBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

             request.Content = content;

             var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
             return (response.IsSuccessStatusCode);
         }
 }
```

The method that create JsonBody is,

```
public string JsonBody(User user, Session session){

        var invite = new EventInvite
        {
            Attendees = new Attendee[1]
        };

        invite.Attendees[0] = new Attendee
        {
            Type = "Required",
            EmailAddress = new Emailaddress { Name = user.GetName(), Address = user.GetEmail() }
        };
        invite.Start = new Start { DateTime = session.DateTime_Start };
        invite.End = new End { DateTime = session.DateTime_Start.AddMinutes(15) };
        invite.Subject = session.Name;
        invite.Body = new Body { ContentType = "HTML", Content = $"Some Content" };

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eventInvite);

  }
```

I am getting a Bad Request as response. Is there any alternative to build an Event? I want this code to be very thin as this is accessed in non UI based application

What is the best way to create Calendar Event?

Answer (score 0):

The fix involves setting up the Timezone in the Start and End

```
   string timeZone="Singapore Standard Time";
   invite.Start = new Start { DateTime = session.DateTime_Start, TimeZone = timeZone };
   invite.End = new End { DateTime = session.DateTime_Start.AddMinutes(60), TimeZone = timeZone };
   var postBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(invite, Formatting.Indented);
```